# Mysql clone id with trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_info` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(35) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want that when an user is inserted in table `users`, to automatically insert a new row in table `users_info` that would contain the same id in the `id` column, as the `users` table.
When I do my inserts, I do them like this: `INSERT INTO users (username,password) VALUES ('user1','pass1');`

I believe that I should look at MySQL triggers. I did take a look but I don't know how to retrieve the key id from the users table for every last row that is inserted, supposing that other rows could be inserted in parallel in other threads.

Comment: There seems to be an error in the definition for the `users_info` table: you have `UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)` but the table doesn't have any column named `username`. Also, `id` should be a foreign key to `users`.

Comment: Yes, corrected.
Why should id be foreign key?

Comment: It should be a foreign key to ensure that you don't insert records in the users_info table that don't have matching records in the users table. Also, it can help the database query engine to optimize queries if the relationship is known. If you want each user to just have one row in the users_info table then you should keep the primary key too, but if a user can have many users_info rows (different addresses maybe) it should not be a primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create `AFTER INSERT` trigger, you can use NEW object:

```
CREATE
    TRIGGER `aftInsert_users` AFTER INSERT ON `users` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
            INSERT INTO users_info (itemID) VALUES (NEW.id);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

A trigger on after insert should work if you define default values for the columns defined as `not null`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_users_info 
AFTER INSERT ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO `users_info` (id) VALUES (NEW.id);
```

See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) on triggers for more information.